# How to render json using :includes in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've models `GuestOrder, OrderBatch, OrderItem`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: guest_orders
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  notes          :string(255)
#  adults         :integer
#  children       :integer
#  created        :datetime
#  placed         :datetime
#  billed         :datetime
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class GuestOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_batches, :dependent => :destroy
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: order_batches
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  placed         :datetime
#  guest_order_id :integer
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class OrderBatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest_order
  has_many :order_items, :dependent => :destroy
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: order_items
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  quantity       :integer
#  accepted       :datetime
#  cooking        :datetime
#  ready          :datetime
#  delivered      :datetime
#  cancelled      :datetime
#  order_batch_id :integer
#  dish_id        :integer
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_batch
  belongs_to :dish
end
```

I'm trying to render json in the following method to get a guest_order and its belonging order_batches and order_items by passing guest_order id as parameter.

```
    def getOrderDetails
        #To get the details of a particular guest_order and its batches and items
        @guest_order = GuestOrder.find_by_id(params[:id])
        render :json => @guest_order.to_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at], 
:includes => {:order_batches => {:except => [:guest_order_id, :created_at, :updated_at],
:includes => {:order_items => {:except => [:order_batch_id, :created_at, :updated_at] } } } } )
    end
```

But I didn't get the expected result, only the details from the guest_orders table is rendered. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use :include rather than :includes, not sure if that's significant.

Try using the :include without the :except first, and when you get that working, add in the :except.

Comment: Ya thanks Snips, :include works properly by mistake I used :includes

Comment: Yes, I use the same for HTML and XML.

Comment: Snips, I tried by changing json to html in the method. But it throws error. How can we render it as HTML

Comment: respond_to do |format|
      format.html index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml =>  @guest_order.to_xml(:include => [:order_batches]) }
      format.json { render :json => @guest_order.to_json(:include => [:order_batches]) }
    end

Comment: Snips, I know to use as above you said.. my doubt is in show.html.erb how can I display the output as in the method in my question. Like guest_order details under that order_batches details and under each order_batch the beloning order_items details...